# CSS - How to upscale Unicode arrows?

Tags: css

I have this simple code-

```
    <div>
        <div>&#x25BC</div>
        <div>&#9650</div>
        <div>&#9660</div>
    </div>
```

And I'm trying to make the arrows much more larger -
I've tried to play with this style rules -

```
div{
height:50px;
width: 50px;
}
```

But nothing is happening to the arrows sizes.

So what am I doing wrong here? Is it possible to change it's size anyway in css?

Thanks for any kind of help

Comment: Give `font-size` a try.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wLpnko7z/ font-size works

Comment: The character references should have semicolons appended, e.g. `&#x25BC;`, as a matter of syntactic correctness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `font-size` instead.

```css
div {
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>&#x25BC</div>
  <div>&#9650</div>
  <div>&#9660</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's text do font-size would work

```css
div {
    height:50px;
    width: 50px;
    font-size:50px;
    color:green;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div>&#x25BC</div>
    <div>&#9650</div>
    <div>&#9660</div>
</div>
```